# How would you distribute the same mobile app for different environments (Test, QA, Production)?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, environment, testflight

To distribute different versions of our apps (Android and iOS) we build different flavours.
Each of those flavours would have its own unique app identifier so we can install them next to each other on the same device.

We would also distribute them through Google Play and the App Store via a beta track and Test Flight.

This went fine until last week.

Now Google is telling us we can't have 3 apps (PRD, TS & QA) that are almost exactly the same (only app icon and backend url are different) in Google Play.

Obviously we don't intent to make the TST and QA version publicly available, but I get it that it's potentially possible.

Alternatively I've looked into App Center and Firebase App Distribution.
Which seems fine for Android, but as I understand you can only release AdHoc builds for iOS and you would have to manage all the devices for the provisioning profiles yourself.

I was wondering how others are dealing with this, or is there something completely different that can be done to separate between environments al together?

Comment: How did you solve this issue at the end of story?

Comment: We kept using AppStoreConnect for iOS but switched to AppCenter for Android.

Comment: Could you please tell me what AppCenter is?

Comment: https://appcenter.ms/
You could say it's like firebase, but from Microsoft.
You can distribute apps with it, but also much more, like setting up CI/CD, track analytics/crash reports etc.